# substring strings and compare between them

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

am trying to substring a string and then compare between two string and so on ..

i tried this:

```
for matchdate in matches.data! {
    datesarray.append(matchdate.dateGregorian!)
}
datesarray = datesarray.reduce([], {
    $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1]
})
datesarray = datesarray.sorted()
for date in datesarray {
    matchesarray.removeAll()
    for match in matches.data! {
        if date.prefix(10) == match.dateGregorian?.prefix(10) {
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

this works fine .. but the datearray is not uniq and i need to substring it before like this:

```
for matchdate in matches.data! {
    datesarray.append(String(matchdate.dateGregorian!.prefix(10)))
}
datesarray = datesarray.reduce([], {
    $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1]
})
datesarray = datesarray.sorted()
for date in datesarray {
    matchesarray.removeAll()
    for match in matches.data! {
        if date == String(match.dateGregorian!.prefix(10)) {
            .....
        }
    }
}
```

but this will not do anything! i got no errors but the result is not shown!

why? and how to solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to find? What's the reason for comparing the prefixes?

Comment: Also, if you want unique matches you can create a `Set` with all the matches (instead of using `reduce` to check if the element exists and adding to the result array).

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist if the prefixes match then i want to add them to array...

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist can you give an example please?

Comment: When dealing with dates I suppose there are more efficient approaches than comparing (sub)strings.

Comment: @vadian how to do so?

Comment: Compare dates with `Calendar` and `DateComponents`

Comment: Is `matchdate.dateGregorian` a Date or a String?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  "date_gregorian": "2018-08-30 18:40:00",

Comment: @vadian can you give me an example please

Comment: You can check if two `Date` instances are in the same day with `Calendar.current.compare(date1, to: date2, toGranularity: .day) == .orderedSame`

Comment: but i have strings like this: "2018-08-30 18:40:00", and i want to ignore the time and just compare the dates @vadian

Comment: @vadian thanks :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @vadian said .. i just converted them to date:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:matchdate.dateGregorian!)!
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)
let finalDate = calendar.date(from:components)
```

and then compared between them like this:

```
if matchdate == finalDate{
 .....
}
```

and problem is solved and everything working great now :)!